# How can I sort Openvas Reports by a specific date?

Tags: security, reporting, openvas

Either using omp CLI or the OpenVAS GUI I am not able to create a filter where I can see all the reports from a specific date(either today, yesterday or any specific day), even though I can sort them in ascending - descending order of date. Can anyone help me find out if OpenVAS even supports this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like modified>2020-01-01

But first of all because you are using omp cli I strongly advise to update your installation. See https://community.greenbone.net/t/about-the-greenbone-source-edition-gse-category/176 for supported GVM (formerly known as OpenVAS) versions.

Additionally omp cli is unmaintained and abandoned please take a look at https://gvm-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific way that I can find to check sheets between two dates, however, I found a regex which would give you everything younger than a day:

```
created > -1d
```

similarly older than a day would be :

```
created < -1d
```

For a week it is :

```
created < -1w
created > -1w
```